# Is there a way do modify the values of properties of __PHP_Incomplete_Class instance?

Tags: php, serialization

My problem is basically the following. I have databases, which store serialized objects which were instances of classes that I don't have access to and in these objects there's information related to the previous host, domain e.t.c. where the website was located. I am trying to replace that information via a recursive search with current info, but the problem is, that when unserializing these objects, I am getting instances of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`, which properties as far as I can tell aren't writable.So, is there a way to modify the values of properties in an object of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`?

Comment: Take a look at [the note in the `unserialize()` manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#refsect1-function.unserialize-parameters). Never used it but might help you.

Comment: @ishegg That would help, if I had access to the files with the class definitions, so I could include them in run time.